# How to assign different points per answer in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created an assessment using google forms. I have a few questions which there is no wrong answer. For example, Question 1 has options A, B, and C. The user can pick any option and still be right. However, I want to assign a different point value for each option. So picking A would give them 1 point, B 2 points, and C 3 points. Is there a way to do that using Forms? When assigning points in the answer key, it looks like I can only assign 1 point value that is used for options A, B, and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could definitely do that with Forms + apps script. But it would be difficult to do with forms alone unless you're using lots of plug-ins.
You could code a scoring system depending on the formResponse and email the results or store them in a sheet.